# SVG Mapping With MouseOver Labels

Tags: svg, d3.js

I am trying to combine two tutorials/examples.
[Basic choropleth](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/choropleth.html)
[Dynamic update of data](http://www.danielroot.info/2013/02/visualizing-census-with-d3js.html)

While I have implemented the update of the data from the Census API and gotten the map colors to change based on the values, I have not been able to add the name/value items to the SVG such that if you mouse over a county in the map it will show a tooltipe of the : .

From the first example I believe what I need is:

`.text(function(d) { return d.properties.name + ": " + data[pad(d.id)] + "%"; });`

However when I add where it looks to my like it should go I get the error that:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

This is the code I am using to generate:

```
function showData() {
    acsData = document.getElementById('measure').value;
    console.log('Gettting data for: ' + acsData);
    var jsonRequest = 'http://api.census.gov/data/2011/acs5?key=<mykey>&get=' + acsData + ',NAME&for=county:*&in=state:*';

    console.log(acsData);
    var dataSet = [];
    d3.json(jsonRequest, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            if (key > 0) {
                var apiValue = parseInt(val[0], 10);
                var apiState = val[2].toString();
                var apiCounty = val[3].toString();
                var elmentArray = [apiState, apiCounty, apiValue]
                dataSet.push(elmentArray);
                //console.log(elmentArray);
                //console.log(dataSet.length);
            }
        });

        var rateById = {};
        var maxVal; var minVal; var maxFips, minFips, maxCounty, minCounty;
        var vals = [];

        dataSet.forEach(function (d) {
            var fips = parseInt(d[0] + d[1], 10);
            //console.log(fips);
            if (fips !== 0 && fips.toString().substr(3) != '000') {
                var val = parseFloat(d[2], 10);
                if (val > maxVal || maxVal == null) { maxVal = val; maxFips = fips; }
                if (val < minVal || minVal == null) { minVal = val; minFips = fips; }
                rateById[fips] = +val;
                vals.push(val);
            }
        });
        countyFips.forEach(function (c) {
            if (parseInt(c.StateFips + c.CountyFips) == maxFips) maxCounty = c.CountyName + ', ' + c.State;
            if (parseInt(c.StateFips + c.CountyFips) == minFips) minCounty = c.CountyName + ', ' + c.State;
        });
        vals = vals.sort(d3.ascending);
        quantize = d3.scale.quantile()
        .domain(vals)
        .range(d3.range(20).map(function (i) {
            return color(i);
        }));

        mapSvg.select('g').selectAll('path')
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .style("fill", function (d) {
            return quantize(rateById[d.id]);
        });

        keySvg.select('g').remove();
        var keysEnter = keySvg.append('g').selectAll('circle')
                .data(d3.range(0, 21, 2))
                .enter();
        keysEnter
                .append('circle')
                .attr('cy', function (i) { return (i + 1) * 14; })
                .attr('cx', 12)
                .attr('r', 10)
                .style('fill', color);

        keysEnter
                .append('text')
                .attr('class', 'keyLabel')
                .attr('y', function (i) { return ((i + 1) * 14) + 5; })
                .attr('x', 26)
                .text(function (i) {
                    var keyLabel;
                    if (i == 0) keyLabel = d3.round(minVal || 0, 1) + ' ' + minCounty;
                    if (i != 0 && i != 20) keyLabel = d3.round(quantize.quantiles()[i], 1);
                    if (i == 20) keyLabel = d3.round(maxVal || 0, 1) + ' ' + maxCounty;
                    return keyLabel;
                });
    });
}
var containerWidth = 640,
                     baseWidth = 960,
                     baseStrokeWidth = 1,
                     scaleFactor = containerWidth / baseWidth;
function prepareMap() {
    mapSvg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "counties")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.object(us, us.objects.counties).geometries)
        .enter().append("path")
        .style("fill", function (d) { return '#ccc' })
        .attr("d", path);

    mapSvg.append("path")
         .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function (a, b) { return a.id !== b.id; }))
         .attr("class", "states")
         .attr("d", path)
         .append("svg:title")
         .text(function (d) { return d.properties.name + ": " + data[pad(d.id)] + "%"; });
}

function click(d) {
    var x = 0,
                y = 0,
                k = 1;

    if (d && centered !== d) {
        var centroid = path.centroid(d);
        x = -centroid[0] / 4;
        y = -centroid[1] / 4;
        k = 2;
        centered = d;
    } else {
        centered = null;
    }

    mapSvg.selectAll("path")
                .classed("active", centered && function (d) { return d === centered; });

    mapSvg.selectAll('g').transition()
                .duration(1000)
                .attr("transform", "scale(" + k + ")translate(" + x + "," + y + ")")
                .style("stroke-width", 1.5 / k + "px");
}

function ready(error, usData, countyFipsData) {
    us = usData;
    countyFips = countyFipsData;
    prepareMap();
    showData();
}
```

Comment: My guess is that it's simply `d.name`. And you probably want to set `title` and not `text`.

Comment: Yes, `d.name` no longer throws error. Now, however, it is undefined mouseover. Baby steps I suppose. Currently using `.text(function (d) { return d.name + ": " + d.value + "%"; });` this returns "undefined: undefined%".

Comment: My first journey into d3 and SVG. So, it looks like I never actually send in the value or the name from the list. The SVG on screen just has a different fill color applied based on the value of the data. Will need to add name/value. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: The name of the attributes you need to query depends on the data you pass in. Probably easiest to simply print `d` to the debug console and figure it out from there.

Comment: Tried adding console.log(d) but i get that "d is not defined" this is after I set `text...;`.

Comment: Well, this is a shame. The US county json file I am using does not, in fact contain the name attribute. How to add the name attribute? More research.